# Social Framework for WatchKit

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to create an Apple Watch app that allows users to share things right from their wrist.

Is there a built-in Social framework for Apple Watch comparable to the Social framework on iOS?

Comment: Use the containing iOS to do so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a social framework in WatchKit. You could hand off to the phone to do it, but I'm not certain that would be a great user experience.